# ios voip app can running in background?

Tags: ios, background

from the apple documents, these are three type app can running at the background.
1.music
2.location
3.voip

so I apply my app as a voip, and I have a socket on to listen others to connect(as a server).  So my app can running in the background and recv data from others connect?  If can,  so we can  develop a application to download file in the background?

I don't know is it right by this way?  Any one know this?

Comment: If your app doesn't actually offer VoIP services, it is very likely that Apple will reject it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can enable the VoIP background mode to allow your app to run in the background. But, if your app does not actually provide a VoIP function, then Apple will almost certainly reject the app. You can use this mode as a means to do ad hoc testing, if that helps, but it won't fly on the App Store.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, please refer to [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12)